# How to turn off autoplay for watch later playlist in Youtube App for iOS

Tags: ios, youtube

YouTube has built the annoying "feature" of autoplay within the Watch Later playlist into its recent iOS update. Is there any way to turn it off?

I love falling asleep to a video that I pick from my Watch Later and I don't want it to keep playing and playing more and more videos long after I'm asleep when all I want is to see that one video I picked.

Answer (score 2):

One trick.

Click share button. Choose "message" option to get a link. Open safari and paste the link. Then. Enter. Now the youtube app pops again. And no more hassle. Play only one vid.

Answer (score 0):

From Google Playlists on iOS

> Playing videos in a playlist
>
> While viewing a video in a playlist, touch the View playlist playlist
>   icon to browse other videos in the same playlist.
>
> You can choose to let the playlist autoplay, or you can touch any
>   other video in the list.

Comment: So it's not possible to turn autoplay off. The "you can choose to let the playlist autoplay" is deceptive since the other choice you have is to not watch the video at all